# NodeJS : Parse not saving record

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I have the following code for saving data to the table.

```
let Parse = require('parse').Parse;

export const gameInsert = async (data) => {    
  try {
      const game = Parse.Object.extend('Table');
      const query = new game();
    data.forEach((item) => {
      query.set('name', 'NewName');
      query.save();
    }, this);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

But it gives me no warning or error and the record is not saving. What am i missing ?

Comment: the `set` and `save` are methods for objects like `game` memeber, isn't it? 
while `query` is used only for query?

Comment: @AmiHollander but its per the docs.

Comment: are you sure? I looked at the API and didn't saw it at first sight.

Comment: @AmiHollander Here is the link  , I tried the same but no luck the error is gone but the record is not saving to the db http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#saving-objects.

Comment: Updating my question

Comment: @AmiHollander Question updated

Answer (score 0):

Have you try, query.save(null); ?